# how should i be using python 3.6 and python 3.7 side by side on msys2 and cmder?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-3.7, msys2, pyenv

I'm using msys2 for my dev environment on Windows 10.  It's great, and this is the first roadblock I've come up against.

Specifically I'm trying to install some packages that won't allow me to via pip because my platform is incorrect.  They require a 3.6 platform and msys2 comes with 3.7

I tried pyenv-win, but that wouldn't seem to work within cmder and it also installed some full windows installers of python 3.6.

Is there a recommended way to get another version of python installed using the msys ecosystem of command lines?

Answer (score 2):

I know you want to use msys2, but you should reconsider, the majority of implementation don’t use msys2. multiple versions and multiple environments can get complicated. If you choose to go forward in a more standard way, you could use what I have written below

You can’t create a virtual env with a version of python that isn’t install in your system.

1. Downloaded and install the version of python you want to use, from https://www.python.org/
2. Create a project folder
3. Create a venv calling the newly installed version of python

   - venv is part of the standard library
   - `c:\>python -3.x -m venv c:\path\to\myenv`
   - it created a copy of the python executable in the newly created venv
   - https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/
4. Activate the new env

   - `c:\> c:\path\to\myenv\Scripts\activate.bat`
   - (venv) path\to\myenv>
5. Once activated you can pip install

   - (venv) path\to\myenv> pip install [package.name]
   - (venv) path\to\myenv> pip list

Any script you run from that venv will used the python exe installed in that virtual environment and use the packages you just installed there